# Incorrectly inferring 'any' in a situation involving generic function composition and a Rust-like 'Result' type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, either, zod

- Our codebase has a `Result` type, similar in spirit to Rust's `Result` or Haskell's `Either`.
- I've defined a `compose` function that composes two `ParseFunc` function.

My problem: When I call `compose`, in some cases TypeScript infers the first type argument to be `any`.  This is scary because it happens silently, and will cause subsequent type errors to be missed.

The example was a bit difficult to minimize.  This is how far I got.  ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUFMBcFcAcBcoCCoDkAlSBnWAbadUaAT3klAAocBLAW1vwEMAnUWgO1B3ltdrQSAe1CZYOIjgzY8hYsPYAJZjgDWkfPnTT0AUUEALSK3QBKAFAXIAD3iKhZCmNwFoAHgAqAGlB6AfKAAvC5y0ADyal6BAD6hbnqsrO4BANzWdg6gAMbCnJLxhMGgAN4WoBWgwlE+fsWckABuJv5Ujcz4sJDInmbIsm5evgGloKwwsKzcoA0A7oURam0dXWapoAC+3uWVJsl6vp71TS1Ue8h6fQtDfoElYxNTM5DzA4SJrGdJa5vbG+m2eysITZFg4aRvRbRUo7CrwWAAI3wtGyD2YABM8vhSFU1MhoKwusUCV10pUcnlJITstBFFR4UiUWjMZxsaB2p1uqBeqUNhY+YCsqDVBDXO8kik7rDQAzkajxhisTjqsgAGYdHCUELq-CasmVXL5Ek0umypkKlls85+My8-lWEAQCZIVAyth0TgAc1AyIRrDYpCsTkoAAV3ZAAGKwTjZdzhWDQTyBELLfDIaNqTjCWacW1BQKQuMJ2pUrie-zpCzoyDC8YUo2gejMDRh1ia8IIgBWNegyHcEZD0ls0EgnHR0hKAG0cMhS16ALrIVuaqMx9zMTikfwbVqq2iadHLkwz0ADnCWcn50BH1exo8d7s0wtn-wVizB6-hh895+D0DD0dx1KadZwJMtF0-NtI2jWMNy3HdgmlKcIw4bgNFIYRVVPQcIKPX8cEnCN523d9yFDcNCxDZNr3-GwRzHaQbxg9wuFVExQHjRNAgAfg44tQGQBpmlYStHQAWWYLgKWrKxR1gehQAAYWEfBFFGJFmGyNRinQDStPQXxZkMQQtQwIyTOIPkLEdAAhDEemMN0oPRB4wlAQxVAwAA6VViGDFzPPQODiC4SRIAxKosPQZTVNMLzrLATxHKCzdiGyZgJFwEhHI-bJjC09jaUbWhwR9ZgR3YPZFBwLzQAsQ0CngL8ux7ABGYomxbZrH2gKgynJVVZ2CQJpF4yEvL2KhdJYQxzAEhYvOqKgYsULy9LUMw-jWerKSEcYwnakImqg78aVaqho2rPcGnRbbaCwqh9rcVrFo2+scBUyAvNUz1HrFaAXo5LofJ+Wz7O5MjIu83yOF0YKHTAENWGEJFIAUz1hCy5hZmYHF7tAABJHIOnwDA5gWSJgA+EKjXClzMJkf7XuAPZ0AS0AbIAVSOaAPKEehcE1aQEEbOCql59jMukBnIVQxscVyasEVUL6dobY72xamkACYOubSB7y13r+sqQaeGG83ePJyEPimjTZttQSXgppYVtYNaWC0zb+W2hq9v+3Wju6nttYusdIGuyBbvSfG-rCbXXttBrPu+4RfqewgE6Br7VVBsAAHFhGEdEekhhn0B8kLdDdtn2aRlH8DR0AMaxnG8awiXQDYZH5lVGDoFoPJYZmYQhGrWso9Q5EGniv3QD3A8mJjYoaHTThM2zXMLdGhbJum5gHfm8alrdj3NI29I541yBTugABmPWupOo2+ulM2F-wQ9w1vLbL921y3APyDs-Hqd8w5XS4FHO6D0M730Tu9FOP046AK8tnEG6xHSF2LqXZw5dK7D2iipRQtdHQADlwieD0MgAmWEiZ5Q3J6SgnUDbBxpDoEgkNjrMAFhVUA48WD+gHkPVUyMFIpVIH5UQ6AMxZhzOgRA7NyT9j-ABBiwETxzk9Lhb+zEZGb23P4dmSVRzQ2IIw6A0gPzSPXrIzgBlQDmTysPHAzA2LsARDWDKmou5CEbqoIQRNzFdw4c4Kq7AWAVXio6Am6AFISDLBgYKoAPHpUytQVqtpO6aTgB0H0tA-QBkJrE0A8SvTUAAFrF1tFLRJqUu5jmoNrTJxkcDs3ANAc+4RhKqlUvMDcOBZjsRcaQaQgh2EeOgBVZAhhJnwBnCASQ59hDdN6V5XI9BgDMGAAANgAKwAE4ADsAAWAAHHfXZwBWrbLvuc7WiiABEMTmg5A8l6Se1iN5yLlp3ViexJ4fiKuI4gKSvGUEECQQCljRAeP-Kofc7BVSKEUdlSg6y+CN3YEVYS91SC1U+bYquwSSSUFpPAEJlBHGGB4MIHhDAsoeI8s0aQpYaTYhRbMIwFJ2gCA3NkSAwBDQEmYDy2gfLwXcGYA43GoAMKwD4XkdA-sSY4hxpwaAXkHkWCAA)).

```typescript
// Setup: A 'Result' type (similar in spirit to Rust's 'Result' or Haskell's 'Either')

export type Result<T, E> = ResultOk<T> | ResultErr<E>;
export const Result = {
    ok<T, E = never>(value: T): Result<T, E> { return  new ResultOk(value); },
    err<E, T = never>(err: E): Result<T, E> { return new ResultErr(err); },
};
export class ResultOk<T> {
    public readonly ok: true = true;
    constructor(public readonly value: T) {}
}
export class ResultErr<E> {
    public readonly ok: false = false;
    constructor(public readonly err: E) {}
}

// Setup: A parsing library

type ParseFunc<OutT> = (val: unknown) => Result<OutT, string>;

declare const makeParseObject: <FPs extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<any>}>(fieldParsers: FPs)
    => ParseFunc<ParseObjectResult<FPs>>;
type ParseObjectResult<FPs extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<any>}> =
    {[F in keyof FPs]: ParseResult<FPs[F]>}
type ParseResult<P> = P extends ParseFunc<infer OutT> ? OutT : never;

// Main code

enum Color { black = 'black', white = 'white' }

// Bad: The parsed result has '.f' typed as 'any' instead of 'Color'.
// The 'any' causes the type checker to miss later errors. 
const parseObject1 = makeParseObject({
    f: s => s ? Result.err('blah') : Result.ok(Color.black),
});
const result1 = parseObject1(undefined);
if (result1.ok) console.log(result1.value.f); // Bad: Type of '.f' is 'any'

// Problem goes away if I call 'new ResultOk/Err' instead of 'Result.ok/err'
// BUT that messes up many other uses of Result in my codebase.
const parseObject2 = makeParseObject({
    f: s => s ? new ResultErr('blah') : new ResultOk(Color.black),
});
const result2 = parseObject2(undefined);
if (result2.ok) console.log(result2.value.f); // Good: Type of '.f' is 'Color'

// Problem goes away if the arrow function is not declared inline.
const fieldParseFunc = (s: unknown) => s ? Result.err('blah') : Result.ok(Color.black);
const parseObject3 = makeParseObject({
    f: fieldParseFunc,
});
const result3 = parseObject3(undefined);
if (result3.ok) console.log(result3.value.f); // Good: Type of '.f' is 'Color'

// NOTE: If I change makeParseObject's type parameter declaration from 'any' to 'unknown':
//     <FPs extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<unknown>}>
// Then '.f' gets type 'unknown', which is safer because at least I get a type error later.
// I'm using 'any' because (1) the actual library I'm using (Zod) uses 'any' and (2) this
// StackOverflow answer says it's better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974835/163832
//  "I've changed 'unknown' in the inferred type to 'any' because it tends to be easier for
//   the compiler to verify. 'unknown' is a true top type which sometimes behaves strictly
//   with covariance/contravariance in a way you don't really want."
```

Comment: I didnt look at the problem, but when you want like `rust` results try maybe this libary: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-results

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `parseObject` function type. Value of passed dictionary is infered always as a `ParseFunc<any,any>`.

```js
declare const parseObject: <F extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<any, any>}> (fields: F) => ParseFunc<unknown, unknown>;
```

I mean it is not infered at all.

In order to infer it, you should change type definition of `parseObject`.

Consider this example:

```js
declare const parseObject: <Out, In> (fields: Record<string, ParseFunc<Out, In>>) => ParseFunc<Out, In>;
```

Working solution:

```js
// A 'Result' type (similar in spirit to Rust's 'Result' or Haskell's 'Either')

export type Result<T, E> = ResultOk<T> | ResultErr<E>;

export const Result = {
    ok<T, E = never>(value: T): Result<T, E> { return new ResultOk(value); },
    err<E, T = never>(err: E): Result<T, E> { return new ResultErr(err); },
};

export class ResultOk<T> {
    public readonly ok: true = true;
    constructor(public readonly value: T) { }
}
export class ResultErr<E> {
    public readonly ok: false = false;
    constructor(public readonly err: E) { }
}

// A parsing library

type ParseFunc<OutT, InT> = (val: InT) => Result<OutT, string>;

declare const parseString: ParseFunc<string, unknown>;

declare const parseObject: <Out, In> (fields: Record<string, ParseFunc<Out, In>>) => ParseFunc<Out, In>;

declare function compose<OutT, MidT, InT>(
    f1: ParseFunc<MidT, InT>,
    f2: ParseFunc<OutT, MidT>,
): ParseFunc<OutT, InT>;

// ParseFunc<string, unknown>
const schema1 = parseObject({
    f: compose(parseString, s => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) return Result.err('blah');
        return Result.ok('blah');
    }),
});

// Problem goes away if I call 'new ResultOk/Err' instead of 'Result.ok/err'
// BUT that messes up many other uses of Result in my codebase.
const schema2 = parseObject({
    f: compose(parseString, s => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) return new ResultErr('blah');
        return new ResultOk('blah');
    }),
});

// Problem goes away if the arrow function is not declared inline.
const parseFunc2 = (s: string) => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return new ResultErr('blah');
    return new ResultOk('blah');
}
const schema3 = parseObject({
    f: compose(parseString, parseFunc2),
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJRy6W)

Let's have a look on `Result` const which you have used in your first, non working exmaple.

```js
export type Result<T, E> = ResultOk<T> | ResultErr<E>;

export const Result = {
    ok<T, E = never>(value: T): Result<T, E> { return new ResultOk(value); },
    err<E, T = never>(err: E): Result<T, E> { return new ResultErr(err); },
};

// Result<number, never>
const ok = Result.ok(42)

// Result<never, string>
const error = Result.err('some error')
```

According to `Result` declaration you are either infering `ok` type or `error` type, whereas each `Result` should be aware about both of them. See [Rust Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) , each value includes possible type of value and possible type of error.
Now, switch to example which you have provided in your question and hover on `Result.err('blah')`, you will get `Result<any, string>`. It means that TS was able to infer error type but unable to infer `ok` type. Once you change type declaration of `parseObject`, TS will be able to infer both of them.